# Ruby: Insert hash into array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to insert a hash into an array, following this example: [How to make dynamic multi-dimensional array in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234108/how-to-make-dynamic-multi-dimensional-array-in-ruby). What went wrong?

```
@array = Array.new
test1 = {"key1" => "value1"}
test2 = {"key2" => "value2"}
test3 = {"key3" => "value3"}            
@array.push(0)
@array[0] << test1
# ERROR: can't convert Hash into Integer    
@array[0] << test2    
@array.push(1)
@array[1] << test2
@array[1] << test3
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`<<` appends to the array, the same as `push`, so just do:

```
@array << test1
```

Or, if you want to overwrite a particular element, say `0`:

```
@array[0] = test1
```

---

Or do you actually want a two-dimensional array, such that `@array[0][0]["key1"] == "value1"`? In that case, you need to insert empty arrays into the right place before you try to append to them:

```
@array[0] = []
@array[0] << test1
@array[0] << test2    
@array[1] = []
@array[1] << test2
@array[1] << test3
```

Comment: He says that he wants multi-dimensional array

Comment: Thanks, the code you outlined for the two-dimensional array worked

Comment: @Thomas, how did you do that there is no "edited" mark after the answer?

Comment: Good question. I just hit the 'edit' link. Not sure why it doesn't appear. Maybe because it was quickly after I posted it? Maybe because I'm the original poster? Maybe because it didn't have any votes yet?

Comment: can you save @array to active record column?

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to insert into a Ruby array object.  Here are some ways.

```
1.9.3p194 :006 > array = []
 => [] 
1.9.3p194 :007 > array << "a"
 => ["a"] 
1.9.3p194 :008 > array[1] = "b"
 => "b" 
1.9.3p194 :009 > array.push("c")
 => ["a", "b", "c"] 
1.9.3p194 :010 > array_2 = ["d"]
 => ["d"] 
1.9.3p194 :011 > array = array + array_2
 => ["a", "b", "c", "d"] 
1.9.3p194 :012 > array_3 = ["e"]
 => ["e"] 
1.9.3p194 :013 > array.concat(array_3)
 => ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"] 
1.9.3p194 :014 > array.insert("f")
 => ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"] 
1.9.3p194 :015 > array.insert(-1,"f")
 => ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

Comment: Thanks, good to see that there are different ways. I had to run `array = []` first though before inserting anything in the example above, otherwise it would return `undefined method <<' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Yes.  array = [] is the same as array = Array.new.  One usually declares an array variable before inserting into it.

Answer (score 1):

`@array[0] << test1` in this context means `0 << { "key1" => "value1" }`, which is an attempt to bitshift `0` by a hash. Ruby cannot convert a hash into an integer to make this happen, which is why you are getting that error message.